# Don't show comments from someone

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

There is someone who is not my Facebook friend and I would like to be able to keep from seeing their comments.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible only on public activity. If that someone is commenting on any public posts or any of your friend's posts, you will be able to see those comments (make sure you are not blocked by that someone).

If that someone has enable followers, you can get public updates of that person by following him/her.